# AWS EB & Python, How to reset the Elastic Beanstalk accesskey and secretaccesskey?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have configured a Python app for EB, After installing `awsebcli`, I gave wrong user name and access key, now I am not able to change it,

When I try `eb init -p python=3.6 env` it give below error,

```
   ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/test is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplication on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2:2391:application/tryaws
```

I tried to do below commands, eb init , eb config but still resulted in same error.

I am following this guide > https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Answer (score 1):

EB CLI creates a profile in your `~/.aws/config` file.

e.g.

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = AKxxxxxxxxxxxxDKIX
aws_secret_access_key = y0uY3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDd
```

Thus you can change the keys to the correct ones in this file.